# Weird data stored in mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Can someone help me understand what data format this is and can the data from it be retrieved ?

```
a:2:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;i:1446681900;i:1;i:1446767700;}i:1;a:2:{i:0;i:1478304300;i:1;i:1478390100;}}
```

I know this is a very broad and probably off topic question but I found these record in my wp db and I'm not sure what they really mean or how to read them fully. What I was able to understand from them is that these are records for start and end date for calendar plugin. But still not 100% sure if I'm right or how I could turn this into readable data.

Comment: [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not weird. That's serialized data:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1446681900
        [1] => 1446767700
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1478304300
        [1] => 1478390100
    )

)
```

Or more accurately:

```
[[1446681900, 1446767700], [1478304300, 1478390100]]
```

They look like timestamps. The first array being:

- Thu, 05 Nov 2015 00:05:00 GMT
- Thu, 05 Nov 2015 23:55:00 GMT

The second being:

- Sat, 05 Nov 2016 00:05:00 GMT
- Sat, 05 Nov 2016 23:55:00 GMT